# Symfony send array with objects to javascript

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

How is it possible to send an array of objects (entity) back to Javascript after an Ajax request?
If I return the array with the objects with a JSON response, the array is empty in Javascript.
Dump of array:

```
array:2 [
  0 => App\Entity\Firewalls {#744
    -id: 2
    -ip: "test.com"
    -user: "admin"
    -pass: "pw"
    -status: App\Entity\Status {#741
      -id: 2
      -status: "Finalize"
      -update: null
      -time: null
      -firewall: App\Entity\Firewalls {#744}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd encode the json first like

```
$firewalls = [ 'your', 'firewalls' ];
$json = json_encode($firewalls);
echo $json;
```

then parse it back

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "server.php",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (firewalls) {
    console.log(firewalls);
  }
});
```

if the datatype is set as json, jQuery should automatically parse it. If it doesn't work, feel free to share what the browser's developer tools say.

Comment: I tried to encode it to json, but with that array above, my json is empty after encoding the array. Do you have an another idea, please?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `composer require symfony/serializer` ? if not I recommend you use it.

You can the use symfony object normalizer and serialize an entity (or array of  entities) into a json.

**Create a serializer:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

$encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
$normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
```

And use it with your entity or entities:

```
$this->serializer->serialize($data, 'json');
```

[You can read more about this here.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I get the error: Serialization for the format "json" is not supported.

Comment: I edited the way to create the serialzier, can you try again @Luu

Comment: Ok, now I get: A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "App\Entity\Firewalls" (configured limit: 1).

Comment: Use https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-attributes to not retrieve status.firewall which is the cause of the circular reference